# Unity Android Build Error WIN32 Exception ZipAlign

Tags: java, android, sdk, unity-game-engine

Every time I try to build my game for android, I get this error:

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: 
ApplicationName='.../.../.../.../adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624/sdk/tools/zipalign',
CommandLine='4"/.../.../.../.../Asteroid2(2)/Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk'". 
CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped. I've redownloaded the SDK and that didn't help.

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cant-build-apk-urgent-help-needed-solved.254106/

Comment: Please marked an answer as accepted if you're happy with it, or alternatively state why the answers are not acceptable.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. Find your copy of the Android SDK in explorer
2. Go to `build-tools` and choose a version (e.g.`build-tools\19.1.0`)
3. Copy `zipalign.exe`
4. Come back out of `build-tools`
5. Go into `tools`
6. Paste `zipalign.exe`

Comment: @BarneyChambers Do you have more than one version of the SDK installed? If so, try doing it for each.

Comment: I only have one version of the SDK, I think I might just reinstall everything and try this fix again

Comment: @BarneyChambers also check where Unity is looking for the SDK, you might have it in the wrong directory.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! and i already shared with my blog readers at unity3diy

Answer (score 7):

You need to copy the zipalign tool from sdk/build-tools/android-{version}/ to sdk/tools/

Comment: And copy it to where?

Answer (score 2):

In Unity go to Edit>Preferences>External Tools> in "Android SDK Location" select the folder of android-sdk (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) in my case.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error:

- Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0 (you may have different version)
- Copy zipalign.exe to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ (or in your Android SDK path)

Found [here](https://druss.co/2014/07/fixed-error-building-player-win32exception-zipalign-exe-in-unity3d/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy zipalign as suggested at accepted answer; but if there are no zipalign file in  related folder first you should go tools, run android and then install build-tools

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this simply by updating "Tools->Android SDK Build-tools" in the Android SDK Manager to the latest version.