# Android Build Failed Issue in Unity3D?

Tags: android, build, unity-game-engine

I try get Android build using Unity3D. Please find the below error and suggest me what to?

> Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='D:/xyz/softwares/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk\tools\zipalign.exe', CommandLine='4 "D:\xyz\Unity3DWS\app\Temp/StagingArea/Package_unaligned.apk"

Comment: If you look at the path listed, you'll most likely see that zipalign.exe can't be found there. If so, copy it from your sdk\build-tools\{version} directory to the path mentioned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501944/unity3d-android-build-error-win32-exception-zipalign - same issue